# Why the exponential function is multiplied by 365?

Tags: exponential-function

In Marc Artzrouni’s paper « the mathematics of ponzi scheme” (2009), I’m having some difficulty understanding the logic of an equation. It is assumed by the author that the continuous cash inflow is that of exponential growth:
$$S(t)=S_0e^{r_it}$$
Where *S0* is the initial density of the deposits and *ri* is the investment rate.
Subsequently, he uses the data available on Ponzi’s original scheme to crudely fit the model. The parameters *S0* et *ri* for the density of new investments *S0* exp(*rit*) are estimated on the basis of information on deposits made between the first day (December 26,1919, t=0) and last day (July 26, 1920, t* = 217/365 = 0.58) of the scheme’s history. We also know that on the last day Ponzi collected 200,000 dollars for a total of 10 million deposited over the seven-month period. Under the assumption of exponential growth, and with the year and a million dollars as the time and monetary units, the parameters *S0* and *ri* must satisfy:
$$S_0e^{r_i0.58}=0.2\times365,$$
$$S_0\frac{e^{r_i0.58}-1}{r_i}=10$$
Which yields *S0* = 1.130 and *ri* = 7.187. This value of *So* translates into an initial flow *S0*/365 of $ 3095 a day, says the author.
My problem is that I have no idea why the right term in the above equation is multiplied by 365. Could someone explain it to me, please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For me, the first equation in the system of the two equations to solve should be: S0e(ri0.58) = 0.2 not S0e(ri0.58) = 0.2 times 365. Where does the "times 365" part come from? How to justify this? I don't know precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It explains why it's multiplied by 365 in the sentence before the equation.

[image]

It is because $s_0$ is in units of million-dollar years, and the $\$200,000$ dollars is the amount accumulated in one day. In other words $\$200,000$ dollars a day is equivalent to $365\times\$200,000$ dollars a year.

Comment: Why not just use the equation : Soexp(0.58ri) as defined previously? Why he adds "times 365"? How does he get that? And why it disappears when he integrates (second equation)?

Comment: Why do you think I know the answers to those questions?

Comment: You don't have to answer if you don't know. I didn't see the end of your answer. It helps me to understand. Thank you.